# Windsor with composite WPF February release (Prism 2)

Tags: castle-windsor, prism

Has anyone managed to create a windsor bootstrapper for prism2?

Prism 2 seems to rely on Unity's behaviour of injecting types that haven't yet been registered.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

for future reference

I wrote a Prism v4 Windsor extension https://github.com/bszafko/PrismContrib.WindsorExtensions

and a nuget package http://nuget.org/Packages/Packages/Details/Prism-WindsorExtensions-4-0-0-0

Answer (score 2):

Windsor bootstrapper is already implemented. Look at:
http://www.codeplex.com/CompositeWPFContrib

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [this one](http://compositewpfcontrib.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/23128#285541)?